# rb-inotify-0.9.6.gem missing from rubygems.org

Tags: rubygems

I’m getting a missing gem message from Maven:

```
http://production.s3.rubygems.org/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.6.gem
http://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/gems/rb-inotify-0.9.6.gem
Could not find artifact rubygems:rb-inotify:gem:0.9.6 in rubygems-release (http://rubygems-proxy.torquebox.org/releases)
https://rubygems.org/gems/rb-inotify/versions/0.9.6
```

This gem is a dependency of some other gem and I can’t adjust the version manually.

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a issue with the torquebox rubygems proxy. This is likely a temporary issue and will be resolved soon.

Until then:
The original rubygems site do have the 0.9.7 version of the rb-inotify gem. You can download it from there using `gem fetch rb-inotify -v 0.9.7` and place in your local maven repository and you also have to create the sha1 file for the gem.

If you can't/don't want to go through these steps, I have uploaded the 0.9.7 dir from my maven local at: http://www.filedropper.com/097_1

This file needs to be extracted to ~/.m2/repository/rubygems/rb-inotify/0.9.7 (Assuming your maven local is located in .m2 under your user directory)

Update: changed version from 0.9.6 to 0.9.7, since 0.9.6 was yanked from rubygems as well.

Comment: The new version is 0.9.7. It can be extracted to the local maven repository the same way as described.

Comment: This doesn't work. 0.9.6 has been yanked. I cannot get anything done right now due to a dependency conflict - any advice on updates?

Comment: 0.9.7 should land soon(ish): https://github.com/torquebox/jruby-maven-plugins/issues/81#issuecomment-182273034

Comment: @tommy.bonderenka, I have updated the answer for version 0.9.7

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with the gradle-compass plugin. My fix is to force compass to use version 0.9.5 like this in the build.gradle file:

```
configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.force 'rubygems:rb-inotify:0.9.5' }
```

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't figure this out yesterday so I just changed the build file to use [Jsass](https://github.com/bit3/jsass) . I wasn't as simple to get set up as gradle-compass, but compiles the Sass in about 1/3 the time.

Comment: Can you confirm that resolutionStrategy.force works?  I tried it with my Gradle 2.10 script, and it fails with the same message about rb-inotify 0.9.7.

Comment: You have to downgrade to 0.9.5. But it seem like 0.9.7 i up now. so no need for any force downgrading :)

Comment: 0.9.7 is down for me. This fixed it!

Comment: Where this line should be added? Does this patch also applies to compass gem?

Comment: Since it only affect my compass things, I placed the line together with the compass settings. I needed this because I use compass-normalize, that has "compass" dependency, that has "rb-inotify" dependency.